# Make a grouped boxplot with the recurring/grouped rows in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I would like to make a grouped boxplot like this [image: Grouped Boxplot GGPLOT2]

with elements of a data frame of three columns, ID, an  issuer_bank and a risk score for every transaction.

My starting data frame look like this:

| ID | issuer_name | risk_score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | POSTEPAY | 0 |
| 2 | BANCA SELLA | 10 |
| 3 | BANCA SELLA | 10 |
| 4 | BANCA SELLA | 10 |
| 5 | BANCA SELLA | 33 |
| 6 | POSTEPAY | 0 |
| 7 | POSTEPAY | 0 |
| 8 | POSTEPAY | 10 |
| 9 | CASSA CENTRALE BANCA - CREDITO | 0 |
| 10 | BANCA NAZIONALE DEL LAVORO SP | 0 |
| 11 | BANCO BPM SOCIETA PER AZIONI | 0 |
| 12 | NEXI PAYMENTS | 10 |
| 13 | UNICREDIT | 10 |
| 14 | CREDITO EMILIANO | 0 |
| 15 | POSTEPAY | 0 |
| 16 | POSTEPAY | 10 |
| 17 | POSTEPAY | 0 |
| 18 | N26 GMBH | 10 |
| 19 | BANCO BPM SOCIETA PER AZIONI | 25 |
| 20 | NEXI PAYMENTS | 10 |
| 21 | POSTEPAY | 10 |
| 22 | INTESA SANPAOLO | 0 |
| 23 | CREDIT AGRICOLE CARIPARMA | 10 |
| 24 | CREDIT AGRICOLE CARIPARMA | 10 |
| 25 | FINECOBANK | 0 |
| 26 | UNICREDIT | 44 |
| 27 | BANCA MONTE DEI PASCHI DI SIENA | 0 |
| 28 | UNICREDIT | 0 |
| 29 | FINECOBANK | 25 |
| 30 | CASSA CENTRALE BANCA - CREDITO | 10 |
| 31 | NEXI PAYMENTS | 10 |
| 32 | INTESA SANPAOLO | 25 |
| 33 | INTESA SANPAOLO | 0 |
| 34 | POSTEPAY | 10 |
| 35 | INTESA SANPAOLO | 10 |
| 36 | INTESA SANPAOLO | 20 |
| 37 | POSTEPAY | 10 |
| 38 | INTESA SANPAOLO | 10 |
| 39 | POSTEPAY | 0 |
| 40 | POSTEPAY | 0 |
| 41 | UNICREDIT | 10 |
| 42 | POSTEPAY | 10 |
| 43 | BIBANCA | 0 |
| 44 | POSTEPAY | 0 |
| 45 | INTESA SANPAOLO | 10 |
| 46 | FINDOMESTIC BANCA | 10 |
| 47 | POSTEPAY | 0 |
| 48 | POSTEPAY | 10 |

I would like to group for Issuer_name and make a boxplot of the risk score and compute all in a single chart.

The manual process that I have done is the following

```
df_risk_score_single <- df_risk_score %>% filter(issuer_name == "POSTEPAY")
ggplot(data = df_risk_score_single, aes(x= issuer_name, y=risk_score))+geom_boxplot()
```

which return a single boxplot [image: the single boxplot]

any suggestion?

Comment: It is unclear how, if at all, your proposed "following this road" code is lacking. Do you want it to output something different?

Comment: I was using it as an example not directly correlated to my use case, my main output shold be a single chart with multiple boxplots

Comment: Wouldn't you get that if you used `df_risk_score` instead of `df_risk_score_single` in your ggplot? Why would you limit your data to one issuer if you want to show multiple issuers' data?

Comment: I didn't think that could work without some other transformation

Comment: ggplot is nice that way -- if it works with one discrete item on the axis, it should work for 1,000 (aesthetic formatting challenges aside).

Comment: thank you @jon-spring, I was kind of a dumb to give up before trying but usually ggplot2 gives me a lot of headache, it needs surely a bit of tweak about the formatting side but I can work on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like the following code snippet, which results in the graph shown below.

I used the sample data from your question editing one value. Of course you'll have to improve this code for your requirements and by using your complete data.

```
ggplot(data = df_risk_score, aes(x= issuer_name, y=risk_score, group=issuer_name, fill = issuer_name)) + 
       geom_boxplot() +
       theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) + 
       xlab("Issuer") +
       ylab("Risk score") +
       guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Legend Title: Issuer"))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! it worked like a charm, I just need it to tweak it, but now I can understand how to use the group function within the aes section

Comment: @Andrea - you're welcome. If an answer has helped you solve your problem feel free to mark the answer as accepted.